# I am trying to parse a fixed width mainframe screenshot file with python using struct and string module. I am getting below error

Tags: python-3.x, ipython

In [1]: import string

In [2]: import struct

In [3]: baseformat = '10s 1x 25s 10s 1x 20s'

In [4]: theline = "DD        :   3KZ                   BD NAME   : PETERA QDVISORS LLC"

### In [5]: mytup = struct.unpack_from(baseformat,theline,offset=0)

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 mytup = struct.unpack_from(baseformat,theline,offset=0)

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: Pass the `unpack_from` function a bytes-like object: `struct.unpack_from('10s 1x 25s 10s 1x 20s', b"BD : 3KZ BD NAME : CETERA ADVISORS LLC"*2,offset=0)`.

Comment: what we mean by *2 at the end of b"BD : 3KZ BD NAME : CETERA ADVISORS LLC"*2 ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`theline` is a string, but `struct.unpack_from` is expecting a binary sequence `bytes`.  You can convert it like so:

```
theline = bytes("BD : 3KZ BD NAME : CETERA ADVISORS LLC", 'utf-8')
```

(UTF-8 is probably a reasonable encoding if you're expecting all the input data to be ASCII.)

After that your next problem will be that `baseformat` defines a parser expecting 67 bytes, and `theline` is 38 characters.